# Calling prototype function with .call()

Tags: javascript

I'm watching a course on JS design patters and in one of the examples there is this code:

```
var Task = function (name) {
this.name = name;
this.completed = false;
}


Task.prototype.save = function () {
 console.log('saving Task: ' + this.name);
};

var UrgentTask = function (name, priority) {
 Task.call(this, name);
 this.priority = priority;
};

UrgentTask.prototype = Object.create(Task.prototype);

UrgentTask.prototype.save = function () {
 console.log('do special stuff before saving');

 //why use Task.prototype.save and not Task.save directly. 
 Task.prototype.save.call(this);

};
var ut = new UrgentTask('This is urgent', 1);

ut.save();
```

My question is why inside the UrgentTask.prototype.save function do i have to use Task.prototype.save and not Task.save directly with the .call() method? 
and why if i use Task.save it returns can't read property 'call' of undefined??

Comment: `Task` is a constructor function (`typeof Task == 'function'`). `Task.save` would then have to be a property of the `Task` constructor function. But you never create that property on the constructor function. You create that `save` property on `Task.prototype` instead. So you can only access it via `Task.prototype.save`.

Comment: Thank you for that. now it makes sense.

Comment: Let us know if anything is still unclear.